# Are the matrices with the property $M^3=0$ but $M^2\neq0$ similar to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

Write down a $5\times 5$ matrix $A$, over $\mathbb{C}$, for which $A^3=0$ but $A^2\neq0$. If $M$ is any $5\times 5$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ with the same property of $A$. Is it the case that $M$ is always similar to the matrix $A$?

**Answer:**

For the matrix $A$, I wrote

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&1&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I am guessing that the next part of the question will follow the consideration of the canonical forms and/or minimal polynomials. However, I don't know how to follow. Thanks in advance...

Comment: In Jordan normal form, the matrices will be of the form: $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&a\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ where $a=0$ or $a=1.$

Thus, there are two separate classes of similar matrices with this property.

Comment: In general, for $n\times n$ matrices with this property, the number of classes will be the number of natural number solutions $u+2v+3w=n-3.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So what you did was seeing that the chracteristic polynomial of such a matrix is $x^5$ and then infering there are two options for elementary divisors: $(x,x,x^3)$ or $(x^2,x^3)$. Thanks a lot!